# Plot complex function from one plane to another?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, online-resources

Is there a (free) program or something online that can plot a complex function from one complex plane to another? Like in the picture below? I want to be able to see where numbers go, so to speak, with colors or something.

[image]

Comment: One way to do this: parametrize your starting shape, then graph the function as applied to the pieces. For example, here's the right edge of your example in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28Re%28e%5E%281%2Bt*pi*i%29%29%2C+Im%28e%5E%281%2Bt*pi*i%29%29%29%2C+0%3Ct%3C1), which turns into the larger of the two arcs. This is a bit awkward; it will be easier using a symbolic math program. Look into [Mathics](https://mathics.org/), for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free software / online tool to plot complex functions as maps of grids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399467/free-software-online-tool-to-plot-complex-functions-as-maps-of-grids)

Answer (score 2):

I have never found a satisfactory program for doing the kind of complex transformations you are talking about and have always resorted to doing my own programming (in Matlab, which handles complex number calculations seamlessly). To that end, I did a few quick and dirty calculations for you comparing two transformations. The first is a bilinear transform, shown the two images below.
[image: Bilinear orig]
[image: Bilinear tsfm]
The second is an exponential transform shown in the next two images
[image: Exponential orig]
[image: Exponential ortsfmig]